# Issue Starting up ColdFusion 2018 on Solaris 11.3 on non-root account

Tags: bash, coldfusion, solaris, coldfusion-2018

I have a Solaris system with 3 users ( root, cfruntime , cfdev)

After a successful installation of ColdFusion 2018, the owner of the coldfusion2018 installation is cfruntime.

As cfdev I try starting ColdFusion using the following command

> sudo /disktwo/coldfusion2018/cfusion/bin/coldfusion start

This however doesnt appear to start coldfusion normally, but also doesn't generate any abonormal error/log

Looking at the startup script /disktwo/coldfusion2018/cfusion/bin/coldfusion. The folllowing lines actually starts ColdFusion

```
CFSTART='su $RUNTIME_USER -c "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; 
        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH; 
        cd $CF_DIR/bin; 
        $JAVA_EXECUTABLE -classpath $CLASSPATH $JVM_ARGS
        com.adobe.coldfusion.bootstrap.Bootstrap -start &"'

eval $CFSTART > /dev/null
```

An interesting observation I made was that if I removed the `&` at the end of the `CFSTART`, ColdFusion would start normally (although I need to put it in the background `crtl-z  , bg`)

The ColdFusion process doesn't appear to be persistent after exiting the startup script if started as (cfdev/cfruntime) , but starts normally if the script is run as root.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is there a `./start.sh` script in bin directory

Comment: that script simply runs $CF_DIR/bin/coldfusion start .. so same issue

Comment: Have you checked the log files? Do they have anything interesting to say? (Include them in the question)

Comment: Any suggestion on which log files to check?  ( I have checked  coldfusion-error.log, and  coldfusion-out.log) , but doesn't seem to be anything unusual

Comment: I have seen things similar in old versions of CF. I am MacOS and I can start it and close the terminal window and it is OK. You may just have to keep the terminal open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `nohup` before the `$JAVA_EXECUTABLE` command and sending the output to  `>/dev/null 2>&1` did the trick for me

```
CFSTART='su $RUNTIME_USER -c "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; 
        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH; 
        cd $CF_DIR/bin; 
        nohup $JAVA_EXECUTABLE -classpath $CLASSPATH $JVM_ARGS
        com.adobe.coldfusion.bootstrap.Bootstrap -start > /dev/null 2>&1 &"'
```

I found that it appears that switching to the runtime user `su $RUNTIME_USER` and starting the process in the background caused all jobs started by the shell to close once the startup script completed (sending a hangup signal (SIGHUP) to all jobs started by that terminal) .

The `nohup` prevents the `$JAVA_EXECUTABLE` from closing when it recives the hangup signal (SIGHUP)